# Why Netlogo `range` command with step behaves different below 1

Tags: netlogo

I would like Netlogo to make a range with steps below `1`, but it does a different number of items than using the start number above `1`.

For example,

```
show (range (0.75 - 0.20) (0.75 - 0.15) 0.05)
[0.55]
```

but,

```
show (range (1.75 - 0.20) (1.75 - 0.15) 0.05)
[1.55 1.6]
```

Is there any way to make that `(range (0.75 - 0.20) (0.75 - 0.15) 0.05)` gives also two values
`[0.55 0.6]`.?

Answer (score 1):

Netlogo uses a precision internally that mekes operation like this:

```
0.60 >= (0.55 + 0.05) 
false
```

and

```
1.60 >= (1.55 + 0.05)
true
```

I do not know if this is a bug of Netlogo, but the first logic result is odd because it should give `true` not `false`.

A solution is a procedure to make range lists.

```
to-report my-range [ini fin stp]
  let prec 2
  ifelse fin >= (precision (ini + stp) prec) [
    let mr (list ini)
    let lv ((precision ((fin - ini)/ stp) 1) )  
    let val 0
    repeat lv [ 
      set val (last mr)
      set mr (lput (precision (val + stp) prec) mr)
    ]
    report mr
    ] [
      report ini
  ]
end
```

Now

```
show my-range 0.55 0.60 0.05
[0.55 0.6]
```

Comment: as per http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#im-getting-numbers-like-010000000004-and-0799999999999-instead-of-01-and-08-why , 0.55 + 0.05 is 0.6000000000000001 in a great many programming languages, and NetLogo is just one of them

Comment: @SethTisue thank you. Probably many good programming languages do that, but it is a bit strange the result of the `(range 0.55 0.6 0.05)` command, it should give [0.55 0.6] and only result [0.55]. If you test with ranges above 1 it does different.

Comment: `(range 55 60 5)` is `[55]`, so it seems to me that the correct answer for `(range 0.55 0.6 0.05)` is in fact `[0.55]`. This is in accordance with the documentation for  http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#range . I don't know what you mean by "it does different" in other cases — what other cases do you mean, can you give an example?

Comment: @SethTisue For example, `show (range 1.55 1.60 0.05)` gives `[1.55 1.6]`, and not [1.55]. I am observing different results depending on the data. Sometimes is a right open range operation not considering the max value, and sometimes the max value is considered and included like in `show (range 1.55 1.60 0.05)`.

Comment: Thanks — yes, that seems inconsistent. Looks like there's some discussion at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/1575